# unable to read files from a directory using JFileChooser

Tags: java, swing, awt, jfilechooser

This is a sample folder structure :

```
mahesh
   aaa(folder) 
      aa(subfolder)
         a1(file)
      xx(file)
   bbb(folder)
       bb(subfolder)
          b1(file)
       yy(file)  
   ccc(folder)
       cc()folder)
           c1(file)
       ZZ(file)
   xxx1(file)
   xxx2(file)
```

Note that the parent directory can contain any sub-directories and any files. How can I get all files from my parent directory ?

Can any one help me in getting files using jfilechooser ?

Comment: What kind of code is this? Please post some real Java.

Comment: What did you tried ? There are plenty of code examples of the usage of JFileChooser. Like the official Java how-to : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [`File.listFiles()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28%29) to get the files in a directory.  Call it recursively for each directory.  Beware of symbolic links.

Comment: JFileChooser chooser=new JFileChooser("D:");chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
  chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(true);
                    int option=chooser.showOpenDialog(parent);
                    
                    if(option==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
                        chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File(chooser.getSelectedFile().toString()));
                       System.out.println( chooser.getFileSystemView().getRoots().toString());
                       Myfiles = chooser.getCurrentDirectory().listFiles();